# Creating a new document with a custom ID in a new subcollection

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I have one collection called `Inbox` which has multiple documents. I'm trying to create a new document in a new firestore subcollection in one of those `inbox_documents`. The new document should have a custom ID, here called `folder_id`. The code I have is the following:

```py
# Get the correct inbox document reference.
inbox_ref = fs_client.collection(u'inbox').document(self.inbox_id)
if not inbox_ref.get().exists:
    raise ValueError("Referenced inbox does not exist.")

# Make a new document in the model collection and update it
# with the provided folder dictionary.
doc = inbox_ref.collection(u'folder').document(folder_id)
doc.set(folder_dict)
```

Now according to documentation found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) I can simply assign data to a document within a collection. If the (sub)collection does not exist, Firestore should automatically create it for me.
On [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0) page I found a code snippet which does exactly what I want to accomplish.

> When you use set() to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create. For example:

```py
db.collection(u'cities').document(u'new-city-id').set(data)
```

Its pretty much the same as my code. But for some reason, when I try running my code I get the following **ValueError: A document must have an even number of path elements.** 
I searched for this error online and found that this error will get raised when the provided path has a wrong length. But my path seems to be correct.

When I don't give the custom ID to the document and just let Firestore create it automatically with the following code, then the code does work, but obviously with an auto generated ID instead of the custom ID I need.

```py
doc = inbox_ref.collection(u'folder').document()
doc.set(folder_dict)
```

I also tried using `create()` instead of `set()`, but no luck there.
I'm using the google-cloud-firestore python package, version 1.6.2.

Any suggestions on what I could try next or what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document IDs are not allowed to contain a `/`, which is the reason it failed and gave the error that I had uneven path elements. Fixed this by automatically generating an ID and have an extra field inside the document for the 'real' ID.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shown, the value of `folder_id` is almost certainly not what you expect.  It sounds like you passed an empty string.  You should verify, using log statements or a debugger, that you're actually passing the value you expect.

Comment: I double checked and `folder_id` is most definitely not an empty string. It got me thinking tho, that maybe for one reason or another the string that is passed, can't be used as a document ID. So I checked, and this is indeed the reason it fails. The string contains a **/** and this is not allowed.
I'm not in control on what value `folder_id` is, so I'll have to use an automatically generated ID and have an extra field inside the document for the 'actual custom folder ID'.

Comment: You can post an answer to help other community members as you solved your issue. @JonasBoecquaert